# Prooving compact support on Lemma 9.2 Brézis

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm stuck on a proof of Lemma 9.2 in  Brézis's book (Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations).

He starts by taking $\varphi\in C^1_c(Q)$, where
$$Q=\{x=(x',x_N)\in \mathbb{R}^N;\ |x'|<1\}.$$
Then, he defines $\psi(x',x_N)=\varphi(x',x_N)+\varphi(x',-x_N)$, for $(x',x_N)\in Q_+=Q\cap \mathbb{R}^N_+$. Hence, he claims that $\eta_k(x_N)\varphi(x',x_N)\in C^1_c(Q_+)$ and that is my question. I was not able to prove that $\eta_k(x_N)\varphi(x',x_N)$ has compact support, althought I can believe in it. Could someone provide a proof or idea or some reference that provides the details?

It remains to define $\eta_k$. First take $\eta(t)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$\eta(t)=\begin{cases} 0, & t<1/2\\ 1, & t>1. \end{cases}$$
Thus $\eta_k(t)=\eta(kt)$.

Comment: $\phi $ has compact support, the support of $\eta_k \phi$ is a subset of the support of $\phi$.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. $\psi$ is the sum of $\varphi$ and a reflection in the domain of $\varphi$. Even though a reflection is still compact, it is not true that a subset of a compact set is compact. Note that he claims that $\psi$ can not have a compact support, so he needs to multiply by $\eta_k$ in order to get rid of the hyperplane $x_N=0$.

Comment: The reflection does not change compactness of support.